What type of test should I use for paired categorical data?
Somewhat similar questions have been asked here and here, but none of the other answers are really applicable in my case.
I have a group of people, where in Year 1 everybody is sick. Here I have only one status (SICK). Two years later (Year 2), I check the status of the same people, to see if they are still sick or not. Now, in Year 2 I have two groups (SICK and NOT SICK). I want to test if the change in the number of people who are still sick is  statistically significant.  My first thought was to apply a McNemar’s test. However I don’t have a square table (since I only have one group in Year 1). I also thought about applying a binomial test, where I test if the number of SICK people in Year 2 is less than 100%. I’m not sure if I using the correct test or if it makes sense. Here is an example:
# Example table
example <- matrix(c(0, 10, 0, 11), nrow = 2,
                   dimnames = list("Year 1" = c("No sick Year 1", "Sick Year 1"),
                                   "Year 2" = c("No sick Year 2", "Sick Year 2")))

Here is the output of example, which forms a contingency table
> example
            Year 2
Year 1           No sick Year 2 Sick Year 2
No sick Year 1              0           0
Sick Year 1                10          11

# Performing McNemar's Test
mcnemar.test(example, correct = TRUE)

# Binomial test
n <- sum(example[2,])
nSick <- example[2,2]
binom.test(x = nSick, n = n, p = 1, alternative = "less")

Any input would be great!
